# XSLT1.0 - Concatenate Element

Tags: xml, xslt

I know it can be done with xslt. But I have poor knowledge with xslt.
I have a sample XML like this:

```
<Envelope>
   <Header></Header>    
   <Body>
      <DeliveryInstruction>
        <ShipToLine>
            <ShipTo>
            <!-- Some Element Here -->
            </ShipTo>
            <FreeText Qualifier="" Language="">ABC</FreeText>
            <ItemLine>
            <!-- Some Element Here -->
            </ItemLine>
            <ShipTo>
            <!-- Some Element Here -->
            </ShipTo>
            <FreeText Qualifier="" Language="">DEF</FreeText>
            <ItemLine>
            <!-- Some Element Here -->
            </ItemLine>            
         </ShipToLine>
      </DeliveryInstruction>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I want to combine all "FreeText" in my output XML, something like this:

```
<Envelope>
   <Header></Header>    
   <Body>
      <DeliveryInstruction>
        <ShipToLine>
            <ShipTo>
            <!-- Some Element Here -->
            </ShipTo>
            <FreeText Qualifier="" Language="">ABCDEF</FreeText>
            <ItemLine>
            <!-- Some Element Here -->
            </ItemLine>
            <ShipTo>
            <!-- Some Element Here -->
            </ShipTo>
            <ItemLine>
            <!-- Some Element Here -->
            </ItemLine>            
         </ShipToLine>
      </DeliveryInstruction>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

How can get desire output with xslt 1.0?

Comment: Why is the `FreeText` element in the output located where it is?

Comment: Hello michael, Actually, data is coming from other system. I have no idea why freetext is separate. I would like to combine all freetext to put same element instead of many element. <FreeText>abc<FreeText><FreeText>def</FreeText> is become <FreeText>abcdef</FreeText>

Comment: I didn't ask about the input, but about your expected output. -- In addition,  the empty `Qualifier` and `Language` attributes are confusing: what should happen if they are not the same in all the `FreeText`elements within the input?

Comment: hi  michael.hor, I got your point. At this moment we can ignore "Qualifier" and "Language". Usually, it always empty. Yes, we need to consider other way around if their have any values. thanks for your point

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that the combined `FreeText` element can be placed after (or before) all the other child elements of `ShipToLine`, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ShipToLine">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::FreeText)]"/>
        <FreeText Qualifier="" Language="">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="FreeText"/>
        </FreeText>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FreeText">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDITED (+ speedtest)**

Complete working example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="FreeText[preceding-sibling::FreeText]"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="FreeText[(not(preceding-sibling::FreeText))]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::FreeText/text()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on a xml-file with 1 million lines(137700 `FreeText` elements all in the same `ShipToLine` element) takes 1.3 sec.

Using the xsl of the answer of [@michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68034731/3710053) also takes 1.3 sec.

Comment: This is not a good idea - see here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Hello Siebe Jongebloed, Not sure why not working with <xsl:value-of select=".|following-sibling::FreeText"/>. I change it to <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,following-sibling::FreeText)"/> it working again

Comment: @ib3an Read the provided link to see why this is a "very inefficient" method.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: see comparison . Your solution has the same speed as this "very inefficient" method